# ArcGIS Online Topo Maps

Tags: arcgis-10.1, topography

ArcView 10.1 does not have this kind of topo map to "Add Data".  Where do I find this type of topo map, preferably free.  ArcGIS online does not seem to offer this type of topo, unless I am not seeing it on my side.

[image]

Comment: It might help to include information in your Question about where in the world (and when) this map derives.  I'm guessing US from the "Feet" on the scale bar but it could be an old map from another English speaking part of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not show up under the Basemap dialog, but Esri does host a US Topo map service.  The service uses scale dependent rendering with 4 levels, a colorized shaded relief, 250k topographic, 100k topographic, and 24k topographic.

ArcGIS.com

- http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=931d892ac7a843d7ba29d085e0433465 or

ArcGIS Server REST endpoint

- http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer

Comment: I found what I was looking for and needed for client   http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/GDGOrder.aspx